# Search Using IN Condition in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing Web services for IOS In `cakePhp` and stuck in `IN` condition.

I have a table `dog_temperaments` and it has values `"happy,dependent,shy"`.

Now if IOS send me array (happy,shy) Then I search Like this

`Select dog_temperaments.* where temperaments IN(happy,shy)`

Its work fine but if IOS send me array 0 or any(means search by any temperament) Then How I will Search........

Any means Search by all temperaments

Comment: then just remove the `IN` clause if thats the case

Comment: What do you mean by 0 or any? clarify. And add the code you tried.

Comment: put a condition before your search query that if array is not formed or empty then IN from query is removed.

Comment: any means Search by all temperaments

Comment: You may have to do a messy `array.each{ query.append " or temperament = '<condition>'"}`

Comment: Does it return individual dogs, or breeds of dogs?

Comment: get all dog if temperaments match in search

Answer (score 3):

If it is `0` or any `any` then no need for that condition as it ishould return all of them.

So aassuming `$type` will contain the temperaments as an array and `0`/`any` will be single element for that case.

```
if(count($type) == 1 && in_array(($type[0], array('0', 'any'))) {
    $condition = "";
} else {
    $condition = "WHERE temperaments IN ('" . implode("','", $type) . "')";
}
```

And the query will be like -

```
"Select dog_temperaments.* from dog_temperaments ".$condition
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP is looking for

Comment: you forgot the quotations, or if possible, create dynamic placeholders then bind the values needed

Comment: Good answer but my question is, in case of `$condition` is empty it gives all the results which may not be the criteria I think so..(May be)

Comment: Then just add some default conditions

Comment: `default conditions` may not be the considered as an search logic right

Comment: It depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can check that the array is empty or not like

```
if(is_array($array)) {
    Use 
    Select dog_temperaments.* where temperaments IN('happy','shy');
} else {
    notify Enter proper search key
}
```

Else you anyways get the empty results by using the same query if the array is empty like

```
Select dog_temperaments.* where temperaments IN(0);
```